# jenkins setup password access denied

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to set up Jenkins on my Mac and followed the instructions on the [Jenkins Website](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/getting-started/).

I ran the command `java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8080` on my terminal and then navigated to `http://localhost:8080`.

The site told me to locate the file: `/Users/anee/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

When I try to access this file from my machine, I get a "Permission Denied" error.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal exec

`sudo cat /Users/anee/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword`

enter your password, and copy the Jenkins password.